# How to stop an event while it is running?

Tags: java, events

If I activate `MousePressed` event while `KeyPressed` event the key event stops until I release the mouse, how can I execute the mouse event code without stopping the key event from running?

Comment: I don't get your question but if you wrap your event in with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` then it's gonna to be executed when all other events were processed in the EDT. And your question title is not related to what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many `EventListener` you use to capture events, but you can use a thread submission using a threads pool or something like that.

Maybe, your case happens because of your `EventListener` run in a single thread, so Java-Event use a Callback interface to recall your listener and launch new operations.

Now, the important thing to think is the delay between key and mouse event. It is sufficient to JVM to create and launch a thread ? This depends on your implementation.